# Is Sword's Vengeance a "win button"?

Tags: dnd-4e

In Arcane Powers, the Arcane Sword epic destiny gives you the Sword's Vengeance daily power that basically lets you keep fighting in an untargetable state after you die. Even if you were fighting the craziest god ever, wouldn't this power essentially make you invincible and be able to kill it?  I just don't see how your party can lose the encounter when you have this power.

> Sword's Vengeance (24th level): Once per day. when you die, your sword fights on in your stead until
>   the end of the encounter. Each round, the sword can move and make attacks as if you were still wielding it. but it cannot be the target of any attack. At the end of the encounter, after a short rest, the sword returns to your body, and if your body is still present, you return to life with 1 hit point. If your body is missing, you will need other magic to return to life.

Comment: If all your encounters are kill everything or die trying, yes? Honestly the rest of the party could get killed real dead and then you'd come back with 1 hp, good luck getting everyone else resurrected.

Comment: Well, we know from Nethack that gods come equipped with a Wide-Angle Disintegration Beam, so your sword is gone too...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The enemy just needs to find a way to end the encounter without dying; if he can flee (maybe  teleport away to safety), the encounter is over.

Since Sword's Vengeance only works once a day, even if you heal up, he could just come back later and slay you properly.

Comment: Not to mention it's a level 24 spell...

Comment: Thanks guys.  You've essentially answered my question of you will "win" the encounter, though you may die on the next one.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be that the enemies take away the body, as the spell states that you only return to life if your body is still present. So the most simplest solution would be to just burn that body to ashes.